# arrange the first character of first name and than first charcter of last name

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

So i want to arrange the `string = "Deepak Pundir"` into an order such as `"Dpeuenpdaikr"` by taking the first character of first name followed by first character of last name, then the second character of the first name, then the second character of the last name, and so on.

I am also looking for more realistic questions on arrays and strings.

Thanks

Comment: And what do you want to happen if the string has fewer than or more than 2 "names"? And what if the "names" differ in length by more than 1?

Comment: What is a "first name", and what is a "last name"?

Comment: Sorry eilon i am student and so just came a random question in my mind, but can you tell me solution if there n numbers of words and vary in lengh

Comment: If you are a student, I highly recommend you attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and if it doesn't work, this site is a great place to get assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm below the rep level for comments so even though I know this should be one I have to put it here. The simplest solution to me would be to split the string into two (either using .split or .substr) and then from there convert into two arrays of characters.

Then, for loop through it. If they differ in size, you'll run into issues, but a good start would be something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstname.length; i++)
{
    mixed name += firstname[i] + lastname[i];
}
```